# Что со стандартной обвязкой класса исключений?

Tags: c++, классы, исключения, проектирование

Это код класса исключений из стандартной библиотеки, который наследуется от базового класса `std::exception`:

```
class logic_error
: public _XSTD exception
{   // base of all logic-error exceptions
public:
typedef _XSTD exception _Mybase;

explicit logic_error(const string& _Message)
    : _Mybase(_Message.c_str())
    {   // construct from message string
    }

explicit logic_error(const char *_Message)
    : _Mybase(_Message)
    {   // construct from message string
    }

#if _HAS_EXCEPTIONS

#else /* _HAS_EXCEPTIONS */
protected:
virtual void _Doraise() const
    {   // perform class-specific exception handling
    _RAISE(*this);
    }
#endif /* _HAS_EXCEPTIONS */
};
```

В самом классе `std::exception` есть определенные `operator=`, копирующий конструктор, деструктор. В этом производном классе и в аналогичных классах этого хедера таких элементов нет. Нужно ли мне в моих пользовательских классах исключений, которые наследуются от `std::exception` и на данном этапе реализованы как в приведенном примере кода, реализовывать конструкторы копирования/перемещения, аналогичные операторы, и деструктор, хотя бы через `default` или же делать через собственную функцию `swap`? В целом, я не вижу когда мне могут потребоваться недефолтные реализации подобных частей в классе исключений, но как грамотнее с точки зрения проектирования? Просто прописать `default, delete` для этих частей и если это какой-то "сложный" класс, то прописывать уже целиком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если по вашему мнению вам не понадобятся реализации этих методов то тогда зачем поднимать такой вопрос ?

С архитектурной точки зрения как раз правильным будет не делать ничего того, чего на данном этапе не пригодится.

Иначе говоря, если ваш унаследованный класс не будет управлять какими-либо динамическими ресурсами то оставьте всё как есть по минимуму, [правилом трёх](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)) (или правилом 5 ти в случае с 11 ым стандартом) желательно воспользоваться именно в этом случае.

А дальше, по мере масштабирования и потребностей в проекте будете изменять этот кастомный класс для исключений как необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

В этом отношении вся идея правильного дизайна классов как раз и сводится к тому, что если все подобъекты вашего класса аккуратно реализуют собственную семантику копирования/перемещения/удаления/и т.п. то вам на уровне вашего класса даже вспоминать о каких-то "конструкторах копирования" и т.п. специальных функциях не надо.

Если у вас нет причин задумываться о какой-то специальной реализации этих методов - значит не надо вообще ничего делать. Ни `default`, ни `delete` - ничего.